# How to check if Dialog was begun?

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework

I'm developing a bot with dialog. I would like to know how to check if the dialog was begun.

The dialog is begun in this way:

```
await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(KPIDialog), null, cancellationToken);
```

I expect to check if the dialog was begun inside bot class.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Your bot calls into the waterfall dialog (based on your one line code), which then invokes the KPIDialog. The bot class is further down in the call stack - how can you check in this case?

On the other hand, if you call BeginDialogAsync the dialog begins - unless you forget to register it using AddDialog(nameof(KPIDialog)) in the parent dialog. I would suggest you take a botframework example and debug through it line by line to gain more understanding.

Comment: Hi @sidecus, thank you for your attention. I call really BeginDialogAsync but after interation with user I call EndDialogAsync too, then the dialog is ended. Inside my bot class, I have two ways and I need to decide wich way I have to go. (e.g If (bot.IsBegun) {go way one} else {go wayt two}). In other words, the dialog.IsBegun determines wich way I have to go.

Comment: Apologies - I misunderstood your question. Seems like you want to get some info out of the dialog when it ends (instead of check whether it has begun or not). In that case probably you can consider using states (ConversationState or UserState based on your scenario). [Here is the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). The dialog can set the state, the bot can access the state to get the info you need.

Comment: Thank you @sidecus. My english is not good, but I'm improving. Your tip was so good!

Comment: Are you able to accomplish what you need with @sidecus's help? If not, there's a lot of different ways to do this. Where do you need to run you "If {bot.IsBegun}" from? Is it inside an `ActivityHandler` bot class or inside a `ComponentDialog` dialog class?

Comment: Hello @mdrichardson-MSFT, inside an ActivityHandler bot class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of different ways that you could do this, but here's two:

## 1. Read the ConversationState

In your `ActivityHandler`:

```cs
public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

    JToken convoState;
    try
    {
        convoState = ConversationState.Get(turnContext);
        var dialogStack = convoState["DialogState"]["DialogStack"];
    }
    catch { }

    // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
    await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
}
```

You can either look at `dialogStack` to see if your dialog is in it or see if the length is greater than 0 to see if there's any dialog running.

*Note: `ConversationState.Get` returns an error if a dialog hasn't been started, which is why we use `try/catch`*

## 2. Use a Public Variable

In your root dialog:

```cs
public bool isBegun = false;

[...]

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FirstStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    isBegun = true;
[...]

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LastStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    isBegun = false;
    return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Then, just check for it in your ActivityHandler:

```cs
if (Dialog.isBegun) ...
```